# What are two people from the same town called?

Tags: vocabulary

We usually use the word 'countryman' or 'countrywoman' for the people who live in the same country. What word do we use for the people living in the same city or town?

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/townsman) site defines ***townsman*** (sense 2) as "a native or inhabitant of one's own or the same town." Same goes for ***townswoman***.

Comment: If I wanna call two people from the same place. How can I use this word? For example is it right? 'You two are townsmen'

Comment: That sounds fine to me. Or "You two are townspeople."

Answer (score 0):

The word ***native*** can be used for this purpose, as was done in [this news story](http://sampan.org/2015/08/chinatown-teen-honored-by-michelle-obama/):

> Henry Santana and Wen Ping Gao, both Boston natives and now senior counselors for PBHA’s Summer Urban Program camps, took part in this annual summit...

and is done on [this travel website](http://www.travelandescape.ca/2013/05/solo-on-a-london-mini-tour/):

> The drivers are all London natives and enthusiasts. They will take you to the obvious places, like St. Paul’s, the City of London, Tower Bridge and St. Catherine’s Dock, but they can also tell you stories you won’t hear elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In American English, the phrase I hear most often is a version of "we're from the same town," "he and she are both from Chicago," or "we both live in Sacramento."